# Should "spiders", "robots", and "web-crawlers" tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

- [spider](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spider) × 22
- [robots](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robots) × 68 - A computer program that accesses web pages for various purposes (to scrape content, to provide search engines with information about your site, etc.)
- [web-crawlers](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-crawlers) × 160 - (No tag wiki, but already has 5 synonyms: crawler, crawlers, web-crawler, crawling, and site-crawler)

Answer (score 3):

All three of these tags are synonyms and should be merged.  [web-crawlers](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-crawlers) has the most usage and would be my preferred canonical tag name.  The tag wiki from [robots](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/robots) could be used for it.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan to me

Comment: Stephen the tag-crawler, good job.